# golang http.Client wrapper with rate and concurrency limiting

Tags: web-scraping, go, concurrency, connection-pool

My goal is to safely consume an API without getting `429 Too Many Requests` error, activating DDoS protection or going over system limit of maximum open file descriptors. To achieve that I wrote this simple wrapper around `http.Client` using worker pool pattern:

```
package client

import (
    "errors"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type job struct {
    req *http.Request
    respc chan *http.Response
    errc chan error
}

type client chan job

func NewClient(
    HTTPClient *http.Client,
    MaxRequestsPerSecond float64,
    MaxParallelConnections int,
) (*client, error) {
    if MaxRequestsPerSecond <= 0 {
        return nil, errors.New(
            "client.NewClient: invalid MaxRequestsPerSecond",
        )
    }
    if MaxParallelConnections <= 0 {
        return nil, errors.New(
            "client.NewClient: invalid MaxParallelConnections",
        )
    }
    tasks := make(chan job)
    go func() {
        jobs := make(chan job)
        defer close(jobs)
        for i := 0; i < MaxParallelConnections; i++ {
            go func() {
                for j := range jobs {
                    resp, err := HTTPClient.Do(j.req)
                    if err != nil {
                        j.errc <- err
                        continue
                    }
                    j.respc <- resp
                }
            }()
        }
        for task := range tasks {
            jobs <- task
            time.Sleep(
                time.Duration(
                    float64(time.Second) / MaxRequestsPerSecond,
                ),
            )
        }
    }()
    return (*client)(&tasks), nil
}

func (c *client) Close() {
    close(*c)
}

func (c *client) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    respc := make(chan *http.Response)
    errc := make(chan error)
    *c <- job{req, respc, errc}
    select {
    case resp := <- respc:
        return resp, nil
    case err := <- errc:
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

I already see comments like "export X to separate function" coming, but please make them more detailed.

- Should I make the channels buffered? If so, how big should they be, or should the consumer provide the size?
- Should I make `MaxParallelConnections` `uint` and ditch the corresponding check?
- Could the problem be solved with a different approach altogether?

I am pretty new to Go, so any and all additional input is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rate limiter to limit the number of requests processed. Think of the limiter as something that causes the program to wait on the line where the limiter is called, till the conditions are satisfied, then it'll continue

You can add it/change this section:

```
for i := 0; i < MaxParallelConnections; i++ {
        go func() {
            for j := range jobs {
                resp, err := HTTPClient.Do(j.req)
                if err != nil {
                    j.errc <- err
                    continue
                }
                j.respc <- resp
            }
        }()
    }
```

create a limiter with a context:

```
    throttlerCtx := context.Background()
    throttler := rate.NewLimiter(25, 50) // immediately handle 25 requests, and process 25/sec; and unblock the limiter at a rate of 50/sec
```

So you could initialise like:

```
    throttlerCtx := context.Background()
    throttler := rate.NewLimiter(MaxParallelConnections, MaxParallelConnections) // think carefully here how you'd like it to be limited
```

So remove the for loop to do with MaxParallelConnections:

```
    throttlerCtx := context.Background()
    throttler := rate.NewLimiter(1, 1) // immediately handle 1, and 1 per second; unblock the limit at rate 1/sec 

    go func() {
        for j := range jobs {
            err := throttler.Wait(throttlerCtx) // this will block code here following: immediately handle 1, and 1 per second; unblock the limit at rate 1/sec
            if err != nil {
            // handle error 
            }
            resp, err := HTTPClient.Do(j.req)
            if err != nil {
                j.errc <- err
                continue
            }
            j.respc <- resp
    }
```